# Having some trouble creating a bootable usb

Tags: linux

I have an iso file named output.iso with which I want to create a bootable usb.
When I run the following command:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom output.iso
```

I see that qemu manages to boot with it so I assume that the iso is OK.
I copy the file to a usb with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=output.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M; sync
```

and then try to boot again with the following command:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda \dev\usb
```

but now I get:

```
No bootable device.
```

Someone has an idea what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dd iflag=fullblock if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress
```

Replace /dev/sdx with your USB drive, e.g. /dev/sdb .
and then:

```
qemu -hda /dev/sdb
```

Otherwise, recheck the ISO's hash

Comment: I just tested with a ubuntu ISO, this should work fine...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still gives me "No bootable device". I think there is something wrong with the iso file. All seems OK with a different iso.

Comment: @kankal your ISO is probably corrupted then.

Answer (score -1):

I got similar issue on my ISO. I am pretty sure that the ISO works just fine with following command. While always failed after dd into a USB. :(

qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom /path/to/iso